# Syntax error with json process ?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have been working a solution for a game which creates stats for two different players then saves to a .txt, For some reason, unbeknownst to me a sytax error keeps on appearing, here ;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\CA2 solution.py", line 29, in <module>
    json.dump(char_data,open("character_data.dat","wb"))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 184, in dump
    fp.write(chunk)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Im not sure what is wrong but here is the code as well,

```
import random

char1=str(input('Please enter a name for character 1: '))
strh1=((random.randrange(1,4))//(random.randrange(1,12))+10)
skl1=((random.randrange(1,4))//(random.randrange(1,12))+10)
line = '%s has a strength value of %s and a skill value of %s'%(char1,strh1,skl1)


char2=str(input('Please enter a name for character 2: '))
strh2=((random.randrange(1,4))//(random.randrange(1,12))+10)
skl2=((random.randrange(1,4))//(random.randrange(1,12))+10)
line = '%s has a strength value of %s and a skill value of %s'%(char1,strh1,skl1)

char_data1 = {
  "name":char1,
   "STRENGTH":strh1,
    "SKILL":skl1, 
};

char_data2 = {
   "name":char2,
   "STRENGTH":strh2,
    "SKILL":skl2,

};
char_data = [char_data1,char_data2]

import json
json.dump(char_data,open("character_data.dat","wb"))


char_data_loaded = json.load(open("character_data.dat"))
```

I don't know what is wrong, so if anyone does could they please help me and point it out and suggest a way to fix it ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You are giving a string input to a file opened in binary mode. `json.dump` serializes the `char_data` as a string as noted in the doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html#json.dump)

So open the file in `w` mode instead of `wb` and the error will be fixed.